# Excel - pivot date values with max function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to pivot date values in a pivot table in MS Excel. I am getting incorrect date values. I do not want "Grand Total" as they do not apply for dates. Is it possible to do such pivots in Excel?

[image: Original data]

[image: Pivoted data]

Link to XLS file download: http://wikisend.com/download/540422/pivot_gone_wrong.xlsx

Comment: you can easily switch of grand totals in pivotTable tools - design sheet at grand totals command. Wrong values seems odd, is it possible to upload the workbook itself to have a closer look?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks for the tip. I have linked to the file to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct at my side.

Please note that pivot tables doesn't update automatically, you need to manually go to pivotTable - Options - refresh to show the latest data.

If you wan't the table updated whenever you open the sheet then you need a macro for it. You can find several guidances by searching for "excel automatically update pivot table vba", one example is [this](http://www.pivot-table.com/2014/10/15/automatically-refresh-a-pivot-table/).

To switch of grand totals: in "pivotTable tools - design" tab at grand totals command select "don't show grand totals".